# AWS S3 costs for when AWS EMR uses it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

When I run an AWS EMR cluster and it reads from and writes to an AWS S3 bucket (or multiple buckets), what are the costs for that data transfer?

Is that data transfer?

1. Free, because it's internally, in the AWS cloud?
2. The normal S3 costs, with regards to the number of requests?[*]
3. Discount costs or somesuch??

[*] Please do not talk about the *space* costs for S3, those are basically independent of my EMR cluster usage, since the cluster is never writing "intermediate" data to S3, only reading input and writing results.

Comment: Would someone please add a [amazon-emr] tag? Thanks!

Comment: I've created the amazon-emr tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [S3 pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) says

> Transfers between S3 buckets or from Amazon S3 to any service(s)
>   within the same AWS Region are free.

Based on this, I believe EMR to S3 data transfer has no cost.

**S3 Request Pricing**

Note that S3 request pricing still applies. That will change over time, but right now it's

- PUT, COPY, POST, or LIST Requests: $0.005 per 1,000 requests
- GET, SELECT and all other Requests: $0.0004 per 1,000 requests

Comment: Thank you! I was sure I saw that somewhere (internal transfers are free), but I couldn't find it anymore.

Comment: What's interesting is that there is **not** a similar sentence under the *Request Pricing* section, which may imply that requests made by EMR to S3 are not free (e.g. data transfer is free, requests are not).

Comment: S3 request pricing still applies. Answer has been updated.